# Debug JS from a Browser within a Windows App

Tags: javascript, windows, debugging, internet-explorer

today I am asked to write some Javascript for a Website which runs within a Windows App. The app uses a browser internally (I guess some version of IE) to render its content on screen, what is represented by a static/local website.

The main Problem is, that there isn't any way to debug that, what is normally possible with the default developer tools of each browser.

So my question(s): Is there any way to start the developer tools by JS, in case the browser internally used is IE? Are the any other ways to pull some debug data out of the app, such that I could view that output anywhere else?

So in case somebody else has already dealt with a problem alike, I would really be interested to get some ideas, how to solve that properly.

Comment: javascript windows store apps use MSEdge.dll . You should debug your external web content using Edge and its debugger . Examine your app source code and find the URL (src) of the webview control... see https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/10/01/blending-apps-and-sites-with-the-html-x-ms-webview/

Comment: That does not work in this case, since the app exposes some global variables, which are not available in the browser.

Comment: I re-read your question... It sounds like you are trying to debug the markup and scripts of html document or resource to a windows forms application using the IE Web browser control. If that is the case you can enable context menus for the WBC from your development IDE (Visual Studio). Then you can right click on the web document and choose the inspect element option. We need more details... to be sure.

Comment: So I can debug with visual studio? Sounds really nice! Could you possibly provide a link to some information about that? I have not much experience with VS and Windows alltogether....

Comment: How to add the standard context menus to the Web Browser Control (Visual Studio 2005). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/177241/how-to-add-to-the-standard-context-menus-of-the-webbrowser-control